# Blogger: Not showing comments

Tags: html, blogs, blogger

I am new to blogger and I have written a blog to help students.

http://mup8085byvishmaypatel.blogspot.in/2017/08/what-is-microprocessor-mup-based-system.html

this is its link.

Earlier it showed comments, but now its not. I have tried almost everything that I got, but it didn't work. I think may be it is because of the Facebook like button that I added in it.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: I saw 4 comments just now though, btw great blog!

Comment: @samAlvin Thanks, it is showing "View Comments" but not showing those comments below them

Comment: I have seen your blog and comments are loading.Though you can try other plugins like FB Comment Plugin and Disqus Comment Plugin.